# Alternatives for "furrowed brows"

Tags: phrases, expressions, synonyms

Question is pretty self-explanatory, and the emotion I'm trying to convey is concentration and confusion, like trying to understand a difficult theory.
Thanks!

**Edit thanks to comment:**

Looking for ways in which to describe quizzical looks.

**Edit thanks to the second comment:** Random Example:

*The students looked at the blackboard deep in concentration, pens clicking, brows furrowed, __________ as they tried to understand the equation*

Comment: The category would be 'quizzical looks'.

Comment: Hi Joshua Ronis, and welcome to the website. I am sorry to be a bother, but we have a requirement for word and phrase requests to include a sentence that demonstrates the sort of context in which you intend to use them, in order to help us know ancillary details regarding your usage case that help to determine what the *best candidate* is while writing answers and voting. See the [tag:single-word-requests] tag for some extra details. If you would please edit this information into the question, it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Tonepoet much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the expression ‘scratching their heads’ which is an expression that describes the body language of people who are having difficulty understanding something.

For example ‘the professors are scratching their heads over the paper submitted by young Jenkinson, which seems to have challenged their existing theories’.

Answer (score 1):

'Frown' /noun/ means 'brows as an expression of displeasure'.
According to Oxford Living Dictionary:
A FROWN is 'A facial expression indicating disapproval, displeasure, or concentration, characterized by a furrowing of one's brows'.
According to Merriam-Webster:
FROWN:
1. an expression of displeasure
2. a wrinkling of the brow in displeasure or concentration.

Comment: Please note, the system has flagged your answer for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer to avoid deletion. For further guidance, see [answer].

Answer (score 1):

How about "frowning" or "knitted brows"? Frowning, according to the Merriam- Webster dictionary means "to contract the brow in displeasure or concentration" . Knitted brows means "to contract one's brows into wrinkles".

Comment: Please note, the system has flagged your answer for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer to avoid deletion - for example, adding a published example or definition for your proposed word(s), linked to the source. For further guidance, see [answer]. Make sure you also take the **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could describe the movement itself : **A crease between their brow, brows pulling together, forehead creasing.**
Hope these phrases help!

Comment: Could you give references for the words you are suggesting and explain why you think they are appropriate?